# Infinite loop in a C++ constructor

Tags: c++, loops, oop

I've got this class in c++ and I'm having trouble with the second constructor: for some unknown reason, the IDE is acusing an infinite loop. I don't have any idea what is causing it, since I've written similar loops countless times.
The code in question is this:

```
class ArithmeticProgression : protected Progression{

    //Constructors
    explicit ArithmeticProgression(double reason) : Progression(){
        this->reason = reason;
    }

    ArithmeticProgression(double reason, int maxIndex) : Progression(){
        this->reason = reason;
        for(int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++){
            
        }
    }

    //Destructor
    ~ArithmeticProgression(){
        delete this;
    }

protected:
    double reason;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You must be reading it wrong, because the infinite loop is in your destructor:

```
~ArithmeticProgression(){
    delete this;
}
```

You keep invoking it from within itself for absolutely no sane reason.

Comment: To clarify, if you call `delete` on a pointer, you automatically invoke the destructor...

Comment: To clarify more, the line `delete this;` should be removed.